# Fundamental group of the complement in $\Bbb R^3$ of the union of the $x$-axis, the $y$-axis, and the cylinder $S^1\times [0,1]$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, fundamental-groups

Let $A$ denote the union of $x$ and $y$ axes in $\Bbb R^3$, and let $B$ denote the cylinder $S^1\times [0,1]$ in $\Bbb R^3$. I am asked to compute the fundamental group of the space $X=\Bbb R^3-(A\cup B)$. It seems that I may take suitable subspaces of $X$ and use the van Kampen theorem, but I have no idea for this. I can't even see a way to compute the fundamental groups of $\Bbb R^3-A$ and $\Bbb R^3-B$. Any helps will be greatly appreciated

Comment: I think this question is quite complicated, since it is hard to build connection between the removed space and spaces that we're familiar with. But there are several things we need notice, the removal of a cylinder is topologically the same as the removal of a **solid** torus, and the removal of any line or axis is the same as the removal of a solid cylinder which forms a tube in your space, then there remains to adjust the position of those tubes. According to my attempt, the space is homotopy equivalent to the connected sum of a 4-hole torus and $S^2$ without 4 points, not sure if its right.

Comment: The main obstacle here is to describe the process of adjusting position of tubes using mappings or using words. Once these are done, then we just need to apply  Van-Kampen's Thm to finish everything. I write these comments because 1. **I'm not sure if my result is correct.** 2. I don't want to cause further confusion about the complicated process (I'm not sure if I could present everything clearly). Maybe someone is able to describe it clearly. But its ok if you really want to see more details.

Comment: If you would like to check your answer @Kevin.S, you may use Alexander duality for the compactification of $A \cup B$ which is easy enough to find the homology of.

Comment: @ConnorMalin Thanks for pointing out this, but even though Alexander duality gives us the homology, we still can't compute the fundamental group because of the abelianization $a:\pi_1/[\pi_1,\pi_1]\to H_1(X)$..maybe I missed something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this "a way to compute" you're looking for?

Let $\approx$ represents isomorphism, $\cong$ homeomorphism, and $\simeq$ homotopy equivalence.

---

**Calculation:**

Let $M=A\cup B$, and $X=\Bbb{R}^3\setminus M$.

> Claim:
>
> 1. $S^1\times[0,1]\simeq S^1\simeq S^1\times D^2$.
> 2. $\{(x,0,0)\in\Bbb{R}^3:x\in\Bbb{R}\}\cong \{(0,y,0)\in\Bbb{R}^3:y\in\Bbb{R}\}\simeq[0,1]\simeq\{*\}$
> 3. The removal of any line is the same as creating a tube.
> 4. $\Bbb{R}^3\simeq B^3\simeq\{*\}$ and $\Bbb{R}^3\cup_f\{*\}\cong S^3$ where $f$ is the attaching map.

Then, we'll go through the following process:

> [image]
>
> We can see that the white region represents the tubes in the space while the shaded region is solid and note that we're looking at the projection of a 3-dim space so the shaded region is path connected. Then in fig.2 the four isolated tube can be moved to the same side and form a 4-fold connected **solid** torus denoted by $T\simeq\bigvee_{i=1}^4S^1\implies\pi_1(T)\approx \Bbb{Z}^{*4}$. The other part is a contains a crossed tube, if we deformation retract the outer outer boundary to nearly the boundary of that tube then we actually get $S^2\setminus\{p_1,p_2,p_3,p_4\}\simeq\bigvee_{i=1}^3S^1\implies\pi_1(S^2\setminus\{p_1,p_2,p_3,p_4\})\approx\Bbb{Z}^{*3}$. Then apply Van-Kampen's Thm, since the intersection is contractible, there is an isomorphism $$i:\pi_1(T)*\pi_1(S^2\setminus\{p_1,p_2,p_3,p_4\})\to\pi_1(X)$$
>
> Thus, $\pi_1(X,x_0)\approx\Bbb{Z}^{*7}$.

The calculation above assumes that $S^1\times[0,1]$ is connected to the $x,y$-axis, otherwise if the cylinder is centered at some other point, say $(100,100,100)$, then the fundamental group of $X$ wouldn't be $\Bbb{Z}^{*7}$ but rather $\Bbb{Z}^{*4}$ (if I computed correctly), thus the position of the cylinder needs to be specified.

---

Hope this helps.

Comment: It's important to mention that $\mathbb{Z}^{4}$ is not just the usual cartesian product of $\mathbb{Z}$'s but the free product, which is quite different.

Comment: @PrakharGupta Yes, thats right, maybe I should use the * notation, is that correct?

Comment: Maybe something like $\mathbb{Z}^{*4}$ will work.

Comment: @PrakharGupta thank you very much, I just edited it..